# .htaccess changing calls to localhost/<file/path> to localhost/something/<file/path>

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have looked through the q&a's and couldn't work out how to do it based from the answers

if I want to make

all requrests to localhost/[file/path]

to

localhost/something/[file/path]

what is the .htaccess

I have tried

RedirectMatch localhost/$ /something/

RedirectMatch ^/$ /something/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
RedirectMatch ^(.*)$ /something/$1 [L]
```

the `(` and `)` capture the original url so you can use it later with `$1` as the first capture group.

note: if you're working with query strings, make sure the flag is [L,QSA]

Comment: that is some what working, i'm getting a infinite loop now

Comment: i'm getting Internal Server Error, but i'm going to give it to you

Comment: perhaps you'd be better served by `RewriteRule` than `RedirectMatch`?